# Group posts by meta_key

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, mysql

I have a Problem with grouping meta_values.
The Query looks for posts with the meta key "company". I want a unique listing of the colors like: blue red yellow

array_unique was not successful and also custom mysql query.

```
<?php
$args = array(
       'category_name' => $cat_name,
       'posts_per_page' => '60',
       'paged' => $current_page,
       'meta_query' => array(
           array(
               'key' => 'company',
               'value' => 'microsoft',
               'compare' => 'like'
           )
        )
     ); 
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
?>

<?php echo get('color'); ?> 
// Outputs yellow yellow blue yellow red yellow

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Current output is: yellow yellow blue yellow red yellow

Edit:

This is the final working code:

```
<?php 
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$cat_name = get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name;


$args = array(
   'category_name' => $cat_name,
   'posts_per_page' => '60',
   'paged' => $current_page,
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'company',
           'value' => 'microsoft',
           'compare' => 'like'
       )
    )
 ); 
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;
$colors[] = get('color');

// Creates an array of all colors

endwhile;
$colors = array_unique($colors);
// Removes duplicates;
foreach($colors as $color){
echo $color.' ';
} ?>
```

Comment: What is `echo get('color');`? What are "colors"? How do they relate to "companies"?

Comment: color is a custom field like company. Every post has this two custom fields >> color and company

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution, according to the asker. He used the [`get()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/get/) method of the `WP_Query` class to retrieve an array of values (colors), each stored with the meta key `color`. Because `[color] => 'Yellow'` may appear in the array more than once, he then filtered the array through the PHP function, [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) which will only return the first encounter of `[color] => 'Yellow'` and ignore any subsequent keys with a value of `Yellow`. The first encounter is returned for each value and you have a new array with no duplicate values.

Alternatively, if you're just handling string values in your array, you may consider something like `array_flip( array_flip ( $colors ) )` [which is faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8321620/array-unique-vs-array-flip) than `array_unique()`.

```
<?php 
$current_page = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1; 
$cat_name = get_category(get_query_var('cat'))->name;


$args = array(
   'category_name' => $cat_name,
   'posts_per_page' => '60',
   'paged' => $current_page,
   'meta_query' => array(
       array(
           'key' => 'company',
           'value' => 'microsoft',
           'compare' => 'like'
       )
    )
 ); 
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
$do_not_duplicate = $post->ID;

// Retrieve and store an array of values for the meta_key 'color'.
// This array may contain duplicate values.
$colors[] = get('color');

endwhile;

// Filter the array to keep only the first key encountered of each unique value.
$colors = array_unique($colors);
// Alternatively, you could replace the above line with a double flip like so:
// $colors = array_flip( array_flip ( $colors ) );

// The array contains no duplicate values at this point.
foreach($colors as $color){
echo $color.' ';
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the codex page for the [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) class, specifically at the [section titled "Orderby Paramters"](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

You will have to adjust the parameters as follows:

```
$args = array(
    'category_name' => $cat_name,
    'posts_per_page' => '60',
    'paged' => $current_page,
    'meta_key' => 'color', /* this has to be included to be able to order by it */
    'orderby' => 'meta_value', /* order by the value of the above key */
    'order' => 'ASC', /* sort direction */
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'company',
            'value' => 'microsoft',
            'compare' => 'like'
        )
    )
);
$my_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: Yeah, but still got duplicate results like: yellow yellow yellow blue black - How can I get only one post from each value? Like yellow blue black?

Comment: If that's what you want, you will have to take care of it in the loop, not the query parameters. Is this the only purpose of the query in the first place?

Comment: ok, have it - check my first post edit :-)